# Get UNC path from mapped drive-letter after impersonation

Tags: c++, windows, unc, mapped-drive

If I call function `WNetGetUniversalName()` to get UNC path from drive mapped in current session, the function succeeds.

But...

- If I create a new logon sesssion by calling `LogonUser()` (The logon user is same as the process creator)
- Impersonate with the logged on user by calling `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` function
- And again call `WNetGetUniversalName()`, the function returns error 2250 (`ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED`)

The thing is I should should be running this process as a service (in SYSTEM account) so I may require to impersonate the user to get the mapped-drives of that user and associated network paths. As I checked, the information cannot be accessed across user-sessions.

Where does Windows store this information, so that are it can remap the drives when user logs-in back? I found that mapped network-paths history is kept in registry under key: `HKEY_USERS\<User SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Map Network Drive MRU` but it does not say if the UNC path will be mapped when user will login back and the associated drive-letter.

Please help.

Comment: There's not one place windows stores this information, it depends on your network setup.
Drives are most commonly mapped either via group policy, or via a logon script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly I believe these drive mappings are stored in the logon session.  Since LogonUser() creates a new logon session it will not have the drive mappings; you would have to use ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() with an existing token.

Comment: Thanks Luke. As I said, the process will be running as a service (in SYSTEM account) and the user must not be logged in. Whenever a user maps a network drive, there's an option "Reconnect at logon". So Windows must be saving this info for next logon. Probably, the solution for this does not require impersonation at all. I am still looking for the answer.

Comment: If the user is not logged in then their profile will not be loaded.  You could load it explicitly, but that is bad practice as an attempt to login while you have it loaded will have bad results.